# Rolling sum for a window of 2 days

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to compute a rolling 2 day using trans_date sum against the amount column that is grouped by ID within the table below using python.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Trans_Date</th><th>Trans_Time</th><th>Amount</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/23/2019</td><td>06:51:03</td><td>100</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/24/2019</td><td>12:32:48</td><td>600</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/24/2019</td><td>14:15:35</td><td>50</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>06/05/2019</td><td>16:18:21</td><td>75</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/01/2019</td><td>18:02:52</td><td>200</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/02/2019</td><td>10:03:02</td><td>150</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/03/2019</td><td>23:47:51</td><td>800</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>01/18/2019</td><td>11:12:58</td><td>1000</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>01/23/2019</td><td>22:12:41</td><td>15</td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Ultimately, I am trying to achieve the result below using

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Trans_Date</th><th>Trans_Time</th><th>Amount</th><th>2d_Running_Total</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/23/2019</td><td>06:51:03</td><td>100</td><td>100</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/24/2019</td><td>12:32:48</td><td>600</td><td>700</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>03/24/2019</td><td>14:15:35</td><td>250</td><td>950</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>06/05/2019</td><td>16:18:21</td><td>75</td><td>75</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/01/2019</td><td>18:02:52</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/02/2019</td><td>10:03:02</td><td>150</td><td>350</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>02/03/2019</td><td>23:47:51</td><td>800</td><td>950</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>01/18/2019</td><td>11:12:58</td><td>1000</td><td>1000</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>01/23/2019</td><td>22:12:41</td><td>15</td><td>15</td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This hyperlink was very close to solving this, but the issue is for the records that have multiple transactions on the same day, it provides the same value for the same day.
https://python-forum.io/Thread-Rolling-sum-for-a-window-of-2-days-Pandas

Comment: A for effort on the HTML tabular data, but probably easier to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to create copy/pastable pandas examples. I've asked a similar question before (maybe the same?) which you can check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357758/forward-fill-column-with-an-index-based-limit/54357812#54357812 -- in the Q I asked for a general "index based limit" but my use case was also a time index.

Comment: Appreciate the feed back, I agree it would be easier to use the create copy/pastable pandas in the future. Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['ID', 'Trans_Date', 'Trans_Time', 'Amount'],
    data = [
        [1, '03/23/2019', '06:51:03', 100],
        [1, '03/24/2019', '12:32:48', 600],
        [1, '03/24/2019', '14:15:35', 250],
        [1, '06/05/2019', '16:18:21', 75],
        [2, '02/01/2019', '18:02:52', 200],
        [2, '02/02/2019', '10:03:02', 150],
        [2, '02/03/2019', '23:47:51', 800],
        [3, '01/18/2019', '11:12:58', 1000],
        [3, '01/23/2019', '22:12:41', 15]
    ]
)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['ID', 'Trans_Date', 'Trans_Time', 'Amount', '2d_Running_Total'],
    data = [
        [1, '03/23/2019', '06:51:03', 100, 100],
        [1, '03/24/2019', '12:32:48', 600, 700],
        [1, '03/24/2019', '14:15:35', 250, 950],
        [1, '06/05/2019', '16:18:21', 75, 75],
        [2, '02/01/2019', '18:02:52', 200, 200],
        [2, '02/02/2019', '10:03:02', 150, 350],
        [2, '02/03/2019', '23:47:51', 800, 950],
        [3, '01/18/2019', '11:12:58', 1000, 1000]
    ]
)

# convert into datetime object and set as index
df['Trans_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Trans_Date'] + ' ' + df['Trans_Time'])
df = df.set_index('Trans_DateTime')

# group by ID and apply rolling window to the amount column
df['2d_Running_Total'] = df.groupby('ID')['Amount'].rolling('2d').sum().values.astype(int)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```